# Python simple POST method

Tags: python, post, methods

A web page has 2 form fields

1:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="30" value="" name="poster" id="id_poster">
```

2:

```
<textarea name="content" cols="80" rows="20" id="id_content"></textarea>
```

Also it has a button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit your own idea!">
```

What I want is, through python to fill in the forms id_poster and id_content and then Submit. If possible, to take the webpage after submitting (to take the result).

Thank you all

Comment: so duplicated... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082361/automatically-pressing-a-submit-button-using-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393738/programmatic-form-submit. Just in a 10-sec search.

Answer (score 7):

Personally I prefer [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/), you would have to install it. The library is a lot better than the one given that by python out of the box.

```
from httplib2 import Http
from urllib import urlencode
h = Http()
data = dict(id_poster="some_poster_id", id_content="some_content")
resp, content = h.request("http://example.org/form-handler", "POST", urlencode(data))
```

Then you can check the response with the `resp`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this (taken from [this example](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml)):

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/somepage.html'
values = {'id_poster' : 'some_poster_id',
          'id_content' : 'some_content'}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```